# htaccess redirect if url doesn't contain some string

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess

I want to redirect all incoming requests to another url if it doesn't contain # and admin. I need it for angular.js, but I have /admin with php

For example:

http://example.com/link-to-article -> http://example.com/#/link-to-article

http://example.com/admin/* will not redirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^((admin|login)(/.*)?)?$ /#%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Also remember that web server doesn't URL part after `#` as that is resolved only on client side.

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` skips this rule for all files.
- Using `!` negates whole match in `RewriteRule` pattern
- `((admin|login)(/.*)?)?` matches anything that is `/admin/` or `/login/` OR emptry (landing page)
- If negation is true then this rule redirects it to `/#%{REQUEST_URI}` where `%{REQUEST_URI}` represents original URI.

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: "This webpage has a redirect loop" :/ How to check if URL doesn't contain # ?

Comment: Doesn't work. Can't load /js and other dependencies. Can I check multiple urls in one line? admin, js, css, fonts, img, data and views?

Comment: And can I add another url to not redirect? /admin and /login for example

Comment: Modified rule and also added explanation with reference links.

Comment: @anubhava: I want to  redirect only when the request is from android and url does not have string 'api' or 'rest', tried 

# Android devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/pwa
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pwa/$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule !^((rest|api)(.*))$ /pwa/$1 [NC,L]
 but not working , pls help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290651/htaccess-do-not-apply-rewrite-rule-for-api-calls